# Warning: move_uploaded_file(Images/shop/icons/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, php-5.3

Hello guys Its me again!

I'm updated my php to 5.3 since then I been getting some errors that I wasn't getting before! One of those is this one.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(Images/shop/icons/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/site/Actions/shop.php on line 61 Warning:

This is the actual code.

```
 if ( strlen ( $icon [ "name" ] ) > 0 && in_array ( $icon [ "type" ] , array ( 'image/png' , 'image/jpeg' ) )  ) {
                        $extension = pathinfo ( $icon [ "name" ] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ;
                        $name = pathinfo ( $icon [ "name" ] , PATHINFO_FILENAME ) ;
                        $destination = sprintf ( 'Images/shop/icons/%s.%s' , $name , $extension ) ;
                        move_uploaded_file ( $icon[ "tmp_name" ] , $destination ) ; // line 61
                 }
```

I did some research but I couldn't find anything similar to my error, I hope you guys can help me and sorry if this was posted before! I really couldn't find it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Permission error = you're trying to read something you can't or write somewhere you can't. This is probably a configuration problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Hi Jan Dvorak, I have read some topics already here on Stack, and yeah I have give all the permission that people have told on the topic to give and seems that didn't worked. And this error just appear when I changed the php version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of your uploading Folder access permission.
Please put Folder permission to writable for public like '777'
pls put it to the entire tree 'Images/shop/icons'

Comment: Hi Nisam, It's already chmood 777! Thanks

Edit: Some reason I changed from 777 to 775 then to 777 again and worked just fine! :o Thanks anyway ga=uys for the help!

Comment: pls put it to the entire tree 'Images/shop/icons'

Comment: Hi, I done that and worked fine thanks! I don't understand why it worked now! Because before was 777 then I tried 775 nothing, then I went back to 777 worked just fine! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Nisam, I know I have fix the problem! Thank you very much for the tip! Like I said on my previous post!